# Inserted Records in Cache on Graph Extension Not Saving to Database

Tags: acumatica

I have an extension graph onto INReceiptEntry. I set up a view for the custom DAC that I want a cache generated for that will get objects inserted into. After I generate one of the objects I want to insert into the cache, I use ViewName.Insert(Object); (also used ViewName.Cache.Insert(Object) with same results) within the graph extension's RowPersisting handler. This normally would store the data items in the corresponding database data table associated to the DAC, but nothing is stored in the DB. Instead of If statement fires and I get a popup stating that the object wasn't inserted. Here is my code:

```
public class INReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<INReceiptEntry>
{
    public PXSelect<EMPWorkOrderINRegister> WorkOrderINRegisters;

    #region Event Handlers

    protected void INRegister_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (INRegister)e.Row;

        var rowExt = PXCache<INRegister>.GetExtension<INRegisterExt>(row);

        //Get Target Objects
        foreach (INTranSplit split in PXSelect<INTranSplit, Where<INTranSplit.refNbr, 
            Equal<Required<INRegister.refNbr>>, And<INTranSplit.tranType, Equal<TranType>>>>
            .Select(Base, Base.CurrentDocument.Current.RefNbr))
        {
            EMPWorkOrderINRegister WOINR = new EMPWorkOrderINRegister();
            WOINR.Woid = rowExt.Usrwoid;
            WOINR.RefNbr = split.RefNbr;
            WOINR.SplitLineNbr = split.SplitLineNbr;
            if (WorkOrderINRegisters.Insert(WOINR) == null)
            {
                Base.CurrentDocument.Ask("Did not insert WOINR:" + WOINR.RefNbr.ToString()  + ", " + WOINR.SplitLineNbr.ToString(), MessageButtons.OK);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Any reason this isn't inserting into the custom cache? Does using a graph extension or executing this cache insert in a Persisting function have anything to do with why this is failing?

By request, the DAC:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace Manufacturing
{
[Serializable]
public class EMPWorkOrderINRegister : IBqlTable
    {


    #region Id

    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public class id : IBqlField { }

    #endregion


    #region Woid

    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Woid")]
    public int? Woid { get; set; }

    public class woid : IBqlField { }

    #endregion


    #region RefNbr

    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Receipt Number")]
    public string RefNbr { get; set; }

    public class refNbr : IBqlField { }

    #endregion

    #region SplitLineNbr

    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Split Line Nbr")]
    public int? SplitLineNbr { get; set; }

    public class splitLineNbr : IBqlField { }

    #endregion

    #region AvailableSNs
    [PXString()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Available SNs")]
    public string AvailableSNs { get; set; }

    public class availableSNs : IBqlField { }
    #endregion


    [PXString()]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr, Where<INTranSplit.refNbr, Equal<EMPWorkOrderINRegister.refNbr>,
      And<INTranSplit.splitLineNbr, Equal<EMPWorkOrderINRegister.splitLineNbr>>>>))]
    public string SelectedSN { get; set; }
    public class selectedSN : IBqlField { }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the keys in your DAC? Also whether the fields are decorated with 'PXDB' attribute? can you post your code for DAC here.

Comment: I added the DAC code.

Comment: try setting, [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)] as @RuslanDev Suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric, there is one major issue with your DAC, which is the lack of key fields.

Additional area of improvement in the INRegister_RowPersisting handler. RowPersisting handlers are designed to either validate the data record before it's  committed to database or cancel the commit operation of a specific data record. For more details, please refer to the [Acumatica Framework API Reference](http://help.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=da626842-8774-4a99-9999-bd664eb0464e)

The better approach for your scenario is to override the Persist method and insert missing EMPWorkOrderINRegister records before execution of the base Persist method. It's also a good idea to use a try-catch statement and delete EMPWorkOrderINRegister records with the **Inserted** status if base Persist method had failed.

Comment: Ruslan, do PXDBIdentity fields work as keys? How do I override just the "Persist" function? I don't see in the customization UI built into Acumatica any option to generate an override for that function nor did I see any in the help (specifically API Reference -> Event Model -> Events). I did realize, after posting, that putting this in Row Persisting is not a good choice, so I'm trying to place it elsewhere, but having difficulty getting that to work.

Comment: A PXDBIdentity field becomes a key field only when PXDBIdentityAttribute's **IsKey** property is set to `True`. Otherwise the system treats PXDBIdentity fields like regular non-key fields. For an example of an overridden Persist method, please check **Step 7.4: Overriding the Persist Method** in the T300 training course. It's also worth checking **To Override a Virtual Method** topic in the Acumatica Customization Guide (http://help.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=6fa2a444-17b4-42f9-9e6a-64e85167626a)

Comment: That was it! Thank you again Ruslan. I went back through my other DACs and realized that I still used IsKey on my PXDBIdentity fields, so I don't know why I forgot to put it on this one.